# 2D contour plot on 3D surface

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a contour plot in 2D which I would like to put on a cylinder. That means that one direction of my 2D plot is the axial direction(z) and the other one is the azimuthal direction(phi) (in radiant). For the Radius I would like to use the value of 0.5.

For phi, z and the data I want to plot I have 3D data:

- 1st dimension: z-direction
- 2nd dimension: phi-direction
- 3rd dimension: r-dimension

which I transform first into a 2D array:

```
YY(:,:)=phi(:,:,63);
ZZ(:,:)=z(:,:,63);
EE(:,:)=E2(:,:,63);
```

(63 is the last entry!)

Than I plot the contour:

```
contourf(YY,ZZ,EE,'LineColor','none');
```

which gives me the following:
[image]

But I don't want to have the picture planar I would like to have it as the outer surface of a cylinder!

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: tip: for the last entry in a matrix dimension you can use `end`, i.e. `YY(:,:)=phi(:,:,end);`

Comment: I guess this will help: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/36176

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you have to extract the height/contour data as a matrix from your contour plot and then apply it as a [texture map](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/visualize/coloring-mesh-and-surface-plots.html#f0-9250) to your cylinder.

This can be done as follows

```
[C, hc]=contourf(YY,ZZ,EE,'LineColor','none'); %Youll want a handle to your contour map.
zdat=hc.ZData; %extract data as matrix.
[Xc, Yc, Zc]=cylinder;
h=surf(Xc, Yc, Zc); %create cylinder
set(h, 'Cdata', zdat, 'Facecolor', 'TextureMap'); %set zdat as texturemap
```

Answer (score 0):

Thx @nivag that workes perfectly!
But I decided to save the plot first and than load it again because then, the picture has a better resolution!

```
figure;
contourf(YY,ZZ,EE,'LineColor','none');

axis off
set(gca, 'units' ,'norm', 'position', [0 0 1 1])

print contour.tiff -dtiff -r100

file = imread('contour.tiff');

[Xc, Yc, Zc]=cylinder;
h=surf(Xc, Yc, Zc);

h = findobj('Type','surface'); 

pic = file;
set(hs,'CData', flipud(pic),'FaceColor','texturemap')
colorbar;
shading flat;
alpha(0.8);

view(25,20);
axis vis3d;
axis equal;
colormap default
```

That look really good but I have the problem that the area next to the plot is not transparent! Is there a way to tell matlab to make the background transparent?